# SQL cuts data while copy table

Tags: sql, oracle, copy

I run this command using batch file.sql with text inside:

```
COPY FROM user/passw@database TO user/passw@database2 CREATE table1 (cl1,cl2,cl3) USING SELECT cl1,cl2,cl3 where ...;
grant select on chema2.table1 to connect;


DISCONNECT
quit
EXIT
```

It copies table data from one database oracle 9 to another. all works good, but strange thing happens, column cl2 I get only in length of 39. Type of this column is long raw. Any idea what is wrong in here? How can I improve this table copy process not to lose data?

Comment: It's quite surprising. I thought datatypes LONG and LONG RAW are not supported at all. Is it possible that some type of implicit conversion takes place? Sqlplus COPY command is a nice feature, but unfortunately is has some restrictions and it was stated by Oracle, that it will no more be supported(extended) anymore.

Comment: yes, it is an old database, but I have no choice, I must deal with what I have.

Comment: I've just checked docs: `COPY` supports these datatypes only: CHAR
DATE, LONG, NUMBER, VARCHAR2. Also a cite from Thomas Kyte portal(question related to LONG/LOB copy): With LONGS (not LONG RAWS) you can use the sqlplus copy command as well.

Answer (score 1):

try this query:

```
COPY FROM user/passw@DATABASE to user/passw@DATABASE2
INSERT TABLE1 (*) USING (SELECT * FROM TABLE1);
```

if you don't have TNS try this query:

```
COPY FROM user/passw@//192.168.3.17:1521/DATABASE_SERVICE to user/passw@//192.168.4.17:1521/DATABASE2_SERVICE
INSERT TABLE1 (*) USING (SELECT * FROM TABLE1);
```

maybe this query can give you some clues for moving data between ora 8i and ora 9i

```
CREATE TABLE tab1 (id NUMBER, long_col LONG);  
CREATE TABLE tab2 (id NUMBER, clob_col CLOB);  
INSERT INTO tab2 SELECT id, TO_LOB(long_col) FROM tab1;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it cuts data as well.

Comment: Maybe it has sthm to with different Oracle. I mean one is oracle 9 the other is oracle 8.

Comment: What is alternative to copy from one DB to another?

Comment: It works fine to copy tables from oracle 9i to oracle 11g, are you sure about that the types which are used in your table,are available and completly same as the types in your second database?